# How to implement soft deletion in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datagridview, soft-delete

I have a DataGridView bound to a object data source. The object has a property "IsDeleted". When the user presses the delete key, or clicks the delete button, or deletes a row in some other way, i want to set the "IsDeleted" flag instead of removing the row. (I then want the datagridview to update).

What is the single point of contact i need to achieve this behaviour?

I don't want to try to handle all the user paths seperately.

Comment: `removing` the row will be done by your code, so just remove the code doing it? Or you don't want the `deleted row` to be appeared anymore?

Comment: Removing the row is not done by my code - it is done by the DataGridView itself. The soft-deleted object will be removed by a filter.

Comment: You can prevent user from deleting any row in your datagridview by setting `AllowUserToDeleteRows` to `false`.

Comment: But i want them to be able to delete the row, i just want to change how the delete is effected.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the event `UserDeletingRow` to `Cancel` it manually and perform your own `deletion` like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e){
   e.Cancel = true;//Cancel the actual deletion of row
   //You can just hide the row instead
   e.Row.Visible = false;
   //Then set the IsDeleted of the underlying data bound item to true
   ((YourObject)e.Row.DataBoundItem).IsDeleted = true;
}
```

You just said that your object has a property called `IsDeleted`, so I suppose it's called `YourObject`, you have to cast the `DataBoundItem` to that type so that you can access the `IsDeleted` property and set it to `true`. That's all.

Comment: Thanks; but that does not change the behaviour of the delete button.

Comment: @DanielOfTaebl What `delete button`? Is the delete button yours or of some `navigation control`? Do you mean the `row` is still deleted/removed?

Comment: Yes, it was the default navigation control; The default navigation control has that effect.

Comment: @DanielOfTaebl do you use the `BindingNavigator`?